# Android app error- unfortunately your app has stopped

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-logcat

I am using eclipse for android app development. When I run my code using emulator, it says unfortunately your app has stopped. In the log cat, it says "Low memory killer". How to resolve this problem? Can anyone answer please..

Here are the stack trace which appear when my app is loading..

```
  09-03 15:54:39.109: E/SysUtils(1892): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
09-03 15:54:40.027: E/libEGL(1892): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:54:40.027: E/libEGL(1892): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:54:40.027: E/chromium(1892): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
09-03 15:54:40.027: E/chromium(1892): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
09-03 15:54:40.027: E/chromium(1892): [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
09-03 15:54:40.396: E/DataReductionProxySettingListener(1892): No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
09-03 15:54:44.051: A/chromium(1892): [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
09-03 15:54:44.051: A/chromium(1892): --------- beginning of crash
09-03 15:54:44.052: A/libc(1892): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 1972 (GpuThread)
09-03 15:57:17.517: E/SysUtils(2115): ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
09-03 15:57:17.598: E/libEGL(2115): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:57:17.598: E/libEGL(2115): validate_display:255 error 3008 (EGL_BAD_DISPLAY)
09-03 15:57:17.598: E/chromium(2115): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(327)] No suitable EGL configs found.
09-03 15:57:17.598: E/chromium(2115): [ERROR:gl_surface_android.cc(23)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
09-03 15:57:17.598: E/chromium(2115): [ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(698)] GLSurface::InitializeOneOff failed
09-03 15:57:17.674: E/DataReductionProxySettingListener(2115): No DRP key due to exception:java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.webview.chromium.Drp
09-03 15:57:18.141: A/chromium(2115): [FATAL:gl_surface_android.cc(58)] Check failed: kGLImplementationNone != GetGLImplementation() (0 vs. 0)
09-03 15:57:18.141: A/libc(2115): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 2155 (GpuThread)
```

Main activity file

```
package com.example.login4;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
        ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.000webhost.com//");
    }


}
```

XML file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context="com.example.login4.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <WebView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvBrowser"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: When your app crashes, logcat should report an error with a complete stack trace. Post that entire stack trace.

Comment: Also, Eclipse is no longer officially supported. You should move to Android Studio, particularly if you are new to Android.

Comment: I try to post the stack trace. But here stack over flow says that there are more characters than the stack overflow allow to post in a comment or in a question.

Comment: Try to include only exception part instead of whole logcat logs.

Comment: How to find the exception part?

Comment: Here I have add the part of the stack trace. Help please..

Comment: @Karakuri answer please if you can.

Comment: @ASW try AndroidStudio you will never want to go back to eclipse :p

Comment: @ASW Did you added internet permissions in manifest file ?

Comment: yes I added internet permissions in manifest file.

Comment: That's not a stack trace. It should look something like [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/android-programming-the/9780132869126/tfDebugging/logcat_exception.png)

Comment: So how I find stack trace?

Comment: @Karakuri Or IntelliJ IDEA if you don't want to limit yourself to Android development.

Answer (score 2):

This is because of your images have heavy memory. In order to avoid this error, move your images to xxhdpi folder.

Comment: I did not use any images

Comment: oh thank-you so much! My issue was that my splashscreen images were too large. running `ionic resources` fixed that issue

Answer (score 0):

In onCreate, the layout is not loaded yet, so

```
findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser)
```

returns null. Then in the next line

```
ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.000webhost.com//");
```

will result in a NullPointerException. Solution is to move the code to the onStart method of the Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView ourBrow = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvBrowser);
    ourBrow.loadUrl("http://www.000webhost.com//");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the first error that occurred "No suitable EGL configs found".
I solved this issue by ticking 'Use Host GPU' in the AVD. Also make sure that the Internet permission is added to the AndroidManifest.xml